# Unity video player on iOS WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use unity with WebGL. VideoPlayer is ok on desktop browsers, but on iOS - don't play :(

I tried **mp4**, **ogv**, **webm**...

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Video;

    public class VideoPlayer : MonoBehaviour
    {
    void Start()
    {

        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        var videoPlayer = camera.AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
        videoPlayer.url = System.IO.Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, "last-scene_all2.ogv");
        videoPlayer.Play();

    }
   }
```

Comment: What is your iOS device specification?

Comment: iphone X, latest ios 12.2

Comment: Don't you have any exception thrown in error log?

Comment: Iam having the same issue? Any luck?

Comment: Are you sure this works as written in browser using WebGL? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html